# Is it accurate to talk about a bitcoin inflation rate?

Tags: terminology, inflation

I have recently seen many news articles refer to Bitcoin's **inflation**.

For example: "`Bitcoin's inflation rate, calculated as the percentage of new coins issued divided by the current supply`" [Source](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4500255-when-bitcoin-meets-inflation)

This seems to be an incorrect usage of inflation, at least relative to how it is used within economics. I also have no clue if there is a unified definition of inflation in the context of bitcoin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **monetary inflation** (growth of coins in circulation), and **price inflation** (the rise of price of goods and services expressed in some currency).

These are distinct but related concepts. The quote you're citing is about monetary inflation, which is - ignoring lost coins - well defined and measurable. Price inflation is a very different concept.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting that in economics, 'inflation' usually refers to what you're saying is 'price inflation'. While in the context of bitcoin, 'inflation' usually refers to 'monetary inflation'.

Is there a reason discussions in bitcoin are not more specific in terms of terminology around 'inflation'?

Comment: @StatsScared "inflation" as such just means "expansion of things". In the context of macro-economy one mostly cares about controlling prices, so it's natural in that context inflation without qualifying refers to that. In the context of Bitcoin, one cares about stable monetary policy and prices are beyond anyone's control, so that's what it means there. In the context of chess ratings, "inflation" means ratings growing for a given skill level. It's very natural in specialized domains that common words get different, specific meanings, depending on context.